# PHP Half-Hour Timezones

Tags: php, datetime

In PHP I am using DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() to get a list of timezones for user selection. This seems to be working fine, but missing from this list are the half hour timezones.

Notably: Newfoundland, Iran and India. Anyone know how to get them back, why they are missing? The PHP docs show them as "don't use these timezones" http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php but they are still used in the world and they don't seem to be listed in the "valid" list anywhere here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't `Asia/Tehran` and `America/St_Johns` work for Iran and New Foundland (India has a fitting one for sure). Both are listed using `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()` for me(7.0) and appear to return the correct values.

Comment: Yep, these are part of the linked group it looks like. The links are shown if you query the listIdentifiers one way and hidden or moved into the "other" group when you query "all". https://github.com/eggert/tz/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Newfoundland

Now I need to figure out is users have progressed as far as IANA in their understanding of timezones.... I doubt it - I'm sure many many users will look for a Candada timezone not a St. Johns one.

Comment: I also found this relevant bug report. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66102 which indicates the way to get them all DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers( DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC );